# Bodegraph with TeXShop in OS X

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot works fine in a terminal window,
extended mode \write18 is enabled, but when I run the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
%%%%    
\begin{document}
%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4,yscale=5/30]
\semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{10}
\BodeGraph{-2:2}{20*log10(abs(3/sqrt(1+(0.3*10**t)**2)))}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this error :

```
./TestBodegraphTiKz.tex:9: I can't write on file `gnuplot/TestBodegraphTiKz/1.gnuplot'.
<to be read again> 
               \relax 
l.9 ...2}{20*log10(abs(3/sqrt(1+(0.3*10**t)**2)))}
```

How can I fix this error.

Thanks

Comment: That is a TeX-error, your question is more on-topic on https://tex.stackexchange.com and should be migrated there soon.

Answer (score 0):

See this ansewers:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31150/bodegraph-on-ubuntu-10-04

You have a problem with the prefix of gnuplot folder.

Just add: `\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}}]`

As option for tikzpicture